# could not access the file imported from iCloud pages

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension

I am trying to build an app that imports files from other apps to my app using UIDocumentMenuViewController(in UIDocumentPickerModeImport mode). I could able to do successfully with apps like dropbox. When i try do the same with iCloud pages, file gets copied to the the folder 'DocumentPickerIncoming', But I get the below error when I try to get the contents of the file.

The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied

Comment: it turns that *.pages is actually a folder, not a file. Now I am struck at how to provide data or file path to upload it to my server.